# How to find $\int {dx\over{e^x(e^x+1)^2}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How to find

$$\int {dx\over{e^x(e^x+1)^2}}$$
First I  put $x=log y$ and then by putting ${1\over y}=z$ I came to an result. But is there any better alternative?

Comment: You could also substitute $u=e^{x}$ or $u=e^{x}+1$ and then use partial fractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Putting $$e^x=u,e^xdx=du$$

$$\int {dx\over{e^x(e^x+1)^2}}=\int\frac{e^xdx}{(e^x)^2(e^x+1)^2}=\int \frac{du}{u^2(u+1)^2}$$

$$\text{Now, }\frac1{u^2(u+1)^2}=\frac{(u+1-u)^2}{u^2(u+1)^2}=\frac{(u+1)^2+u^2-2u(u+1)}{u^2(u+1)^2}$$
$$=\frac1{u^2}+\frac1{(u+1)^2}-2\frac1{u(u+1)}$$

$$\text{Again,  }\frac1{u(u+1)}=\frac{u+1-u}{u(u+1}=\frac1u-\frac1{u+1}$$

---

Alternatively, using [Partial Fraction decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),  $$\frac1{u^2(u+1)^2}=\frac Au+\frac B{u^2}+\frac C{1+u}+\frac D{(1+u)^2}$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are arbitrary constants.

Multiply either sides by $u^2(u+1)^2$ and compare the coefficients of the different powers of $u$ to determine $A,B,C,D$

Comment: You are missing the constants probably

Comment: It should be $-2/u+1/u^2+1/(u+1)^2+2/(u+1)$

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien, sorry for the typo, rectified

Comment: @DebojyotiMukh, really for the typo, rectified